# matplotlib graph dont show Labels and Text and TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

im tryin to show some result as graphs from my table using matplotlib and show in the graph the text

that show the x and y in each point

but it keep show me this error

```
y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

this is my code

```
def total_graphs (self): #pushButton_162
        
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                            password="password",
                                            host="localhost",
                                            database="database")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

        date_0 = str(self.dateEdit_60.text())
        date_1 = str(self.dateEdit_59.text()) 

        selected_day = self.dateEdit_60.date()
        last_day = selected_day.addDays(-1)
        last_day_str = last_day.toString(self.dateEdit_60.displayFormat())

        self.cur.execute( '''SELECT date, total_revenu, total_depance, total_différence FROM total_jr WHERE  date BETWEEN %s AND %s'''
                            ,(date_0, date_1))
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()

        date = []
        total_revenu = []

        for row in rows:
            date.append(row[0])
            total_revenu.append(row[1])


        figure,ax=plt.subplots()
         
        ax.set_xlabel("date(jour)")
        ax.set_ylabel("montant (DZD)")
        line1, = plt.plot(date, total_revenu, marker="o", label="revenu total")
        for x,y in zip(date,total_revenu):
            label = f"({x},{y})"    #"{:.2f}".format(y)

            plt.annotate(label, # this is the text
                 (x,y), # this is the point to label
                 textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
                 xytext=(0,10), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                 ha='center') # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center
        plt.legend(handles=[line1])
        plt.show(block=False)
```

this is the full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 480, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 407, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1863, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2748, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1888, in draw
    if not self.get_visible() or not self._check_xy(renderer):
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1483, in _check_xy
    xy_pixel = self._get_position_xy(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1476, in _get_position_xy
    return self._get_xy(renderer, x, y, self.xycoords)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1346, in _get_xy
    y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py", line 480, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 407, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1863, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2748, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1888, in draw
    if not self.get_visible() or not self._check_xy(renderer):
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1483, in _check_xy
    xy_pixel = self._get_position_xy(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1476, in _get_position_xy
    return self._get_xy(renderer, x, y, self.xycoords)
  File "C:\Users\zakaria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 1346, in _get_xy
    y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

is there a way to fix this error

Comment: it would help to see the full traceback here

Comment: i'm so sorry i' dont understand what do you mean exactly

Comment: the line that's throwing the error, `y = float(self.convert_yunits(y))`, is not in your code - please add the full error traceback, showing which line of your code ultimately leads to the error.

Comment: it seems you have `None` elements in your y variable; total_revenu, is that the case? if so, you can try to replace them with a number to see if that's the issue. alternatively, I'd try to convert the list to a numpy array (with np.nan instead of None) and see if that works.

Comment: Since your [mre] does not include the code that is causing the problem we cannot help. Although it appears that `.convert_yunits(y)`  is returning `None`

Comment: yes i have some empty value in my table i dont know how i will deal with them

Comment: Figure out a strategy that suits your needs and [Catch/handle the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).